How do I specify a server, when passing it as a parameter in a PowerShell script?
I am a PowerShell novice. I've searched for how to pass parameters to a function in a PowerShell script, but all the examples I've found are simple. (Passing names, integers, etc.) I'm trying to write a PowerShell script so I can run it daily to see how long some servers have been up. Using Bing Chat to get me started, I came up with this script:
function Get-ServiceUptime {
    param (
        [string]$Name
    )
    # Prepare name filter for WQL
    $Name = $Name -replace "\\", "\\" -replace "'", "\'" -replace "\*", "%"
    # Fetch service instance
    $Service = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name LIKE '$Name'"
    # Use ProcessId to fetch corresponding process
    $Process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $($Service.ProcessId)"
    # Calculate uptime and return
    return (Get-Date) - $Process.CreationDate
}

# This PowerShell script must be run from a PowerShell prompt running as Administrator.
Write-Output ""
Write-Output "This PowerShell script returns how long the TFS production servers have been up"
Write-Output ""

$TheResponse = Get-ServiceUptime -Name "OURSERVER"

Write-Output $TheResponse

I used the debugger in Visual Studio Code. Debugging this I can see that the variable $Name, in the Get-ServiceUpdate() function has the value "OURSERVER". However, the call to Get-CimInstance to assign to $Service is empty. So, from that line onward the function has nothing to work with. I tried passing in "\OURSERVER" and "\\OURSERVER", but it didn't help. So, how do I pass in a server name so this PowerShell script will determine its uptime?

reading your question again, it's unclear if you're looking for the uptime of a process or the uptime of the server itself. can you clarify ? your current code leads to believe that you want the uptime of a process

When I queried the Chat AI, it used the phrase "Service". I just left that alone, figuring that from PowerShell's Get-CimInstance's point of view, a service and a server are essentially the same thing. If that's wrong, please let me know.

Hehe so that's the thing, if your intent is to get server updatime, then your current code is too complicated. Getting this info can be as simple as (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -Server {addServerHere}).LastBootUpTime. If you want I can add that information to my answer.

You would need to add a new parameter to your function that represents the computer you want to remotely query, currently the -Name parameter of your function is used to search for a service with that name.
Below example adds a new parameter -ComputerName that is optional, if the function is called without it the the query happens locally, otherwise, it will try to connect to the remote computer. Do note that PowerShell remoting is required for this to work properly.
See also about Splatting for details on the usage of @getCimInstanceSplat in the example.
function Get-ServiceUptime {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Name,

        [Parameter()] # <= This one is optional
        [string] $ComputerName
    )

    # Prepare name filter for WQL
    $Name = $Name.Replace('\', '\\').Replace("'", "\'").Replace('*', '%')

    $getCimInstanceSplat = @{
        ClassName = 'Win32_Service'
        Filter    = "Name LIKE '$Name'"
    }

    # if the function was called passing a computername as argument
    if ($ComputerName) {
        # add ComputerName to the splatting hashtable
        $getCimInstanceSplat['ComputerName'] = $ComputerName
    }

    # Fetch service instance
    $Service = Get-CimInstance @getCimInstanceSplat

    if (-not $Service) {
        Write-Error "Service with Name '$Name' could not be found."
        return
    }

    # Use ProcessId to fetch corresponding process
    $getCimInstanceSplat['ClassName'] = 'Win32_Process'
    $getCimInstanceSplat['Filter'] = "ProcessId = $($Service.ProcessId)"
    $Process = Get-CimInstance @getCimInstanceSplat

    if (-not $Process) {
        Write-Error "Process with Id '$($Service.ProcessId)' could not be found."
        return
    }

    # Calculate uptime and return
    return (Get-Date) - $Process.CreationDate
}


Thank you for your answer! I wasn't aware of the fact that Get-CimInstance required more than I was giving it. I've incorporated your code into my PowerShell script. I then ran it, but as you suggested PowerShell Remoting doesn't appear to be enabled. I'll ask for that. Thanks again!

@Rod glad it was helpful. Enabling PS remoting on your servers isn't that hard, have a look at Enable-PSRemoting. Feel free to ask new questions if needed.
